# Power Query Custom Column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need help with Power Query Custom Column.

I would like to have the num_ech as you can see in the picture below which will be dynamically incremented by + 1 according to the id which also changes. As the data will continue growing I'd to create it in Power Query Custom Column.
[image]

Comment: Can you add another column with your expected value?

Comment: requirement is as good as adding 1 for all rows, correct?

Comment: @Siva OP is trying to index the `id` column, not create a constant 1 column.

Answer (score 1):

right click the id column and group by. accept all defaults and hit ok

in code window (or home ... advanced editor) change code from something that looks like this

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"id"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
```

to this

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"id"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "num_ech", 0, 1), type table}})
```

then use arrows atop the column to [x] expand everything except id